# Querying Account Balance of an ERC20 on a Test Network

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I'm trying to debug some code that checks for an account's token balance.

Is it possible to query this on the Rinkeby network? My code isn't returning anything.

```
contract ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint totalSupply);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
}

contract Test{

    ERC20 icoToken;

    function Test(){
        icoToken = ERC20(0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0);
        //this is the EOS token address
    }

    function getMyBalance(address myAddress) constant returns (uint256 theB){
        theB = icoToken.balanceOf(myAddress);
        return theB;
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I input an ETH address into getMyBalance.

Answer (score 1):

The [account on Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0) is not a contract.

Did EOS have a test ICO/token on Rinkeby?.. If so, you should use *that* Rinkeby-specific address.